# ¿Cómo instalar y utilizar correctamente una fuente en tcpdf?

Tags: php, font-awesome, tcpdf

En TCPDF estoy tratando de utilizar otra fuente llamada Graphik-Bold, pero cuando la instalo y la intento usar es como si se rompiera el texto.

[image: Constancia de Liberación del Servicio Social]

Utilizo el siguiente comando en cmd en mi carpeta fonts, para instalar la fuente.

```
php tcpdf_addfont.php -i C:\xampp\htdocs\escuela\backend\api\v1\tcpdf\fonts\Graphik-Bold.ttf
```

En PHP la llamo así: `$pdf->SetFont('graphikb', '', 10);`

Comment: no es necesario utilizar PHP CLI para instalar la fuente nueva, si al final quien la usara es el interprete web.

Answer (score 0):

***Tengo varias cosas que te van a servir:***

1. Puedes agregar un modo de depuración (debug) para verificar si la fuente se está incluyendo correctamente en TCPDF.
2. Puedes utilizar la función `TCPDF::getFontPath()` para obtener la ruta completa de la carpeta de fuentes utilizada por TCPDF.
3. Puedes verificar si el archivo de fuente `Graphik-Bold.ttf` está presente en esa carpeta.
4. Implementar la fuente mediante PHP, en lugar de CLI.

***Ejemplo del codigo:***

```
require_once('ruta_hacia_tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once('ruta_hacia_tcpdf/tcpdf_fonts.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF();

// Obtiene la ruta completa de la carpeta de fuentes
$fontPath = $pdf->getFontPath();

// Verifica si el archivo de fuente está presente
$fontFile = $fontPath . '/Graphik-Bold.ttf';

if (file_exists($fontFile)) {
    // Genera los archivos de fuente
    $fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('ruta_hacia_la_fuente/Graphik-Bold.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

    // Verifica si el archivo de fuente se generó correctamente
    $fontDefinitionFile = $fontPath . '/' . $fontname . '.php';

    if (file_exists($fontDefinitionFile)) {
        $pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 10);
        echo 'La fuente Graphik-Bold.ttf se ha incluido correctamente en TCPDF.';
    } else {
        echo 'No se pudo generar el archivo de definición de fuente en TCPDF.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No se pudo encontrar el archivo de fuente Graphik-Bold.ttf.';
}
```

Otra implementacion importante seria hacer los previos pasos a OOP, con la idea de reutilizar codigo y segregarlo de tal forma que nos facilite el mantenimiento, entonces considera siempre segregar las validaciones:

*Nota:* no hice prueba de funcionamientos por que no tengo el `tcpdf` instalado, pero mas o menos asi deberia de lucir tu codigo al final

```
<?php


require_once('ruta_hacia_tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once('ruta_hacia_tcpdf/tcpdf_fonts.php');

class TCPDFHandler {
    
    /**
     * Description: instantiate Class Static.
     * @var TCPDFHandler|null $instance
     */

    private static ?TCPDFHandler $instance = null;
    
    /**
     * Description: Auto-Instance Helper for static development class TCPDFHandler.
     * @return TCPDFHandler
     */

    public static function getInstance(): TCPDFHandler
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    private $pdf;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdf = new TCPDF();
    }
    
    public function implementFont($nombreFuente) {
        // Obtiene la ruta completa de la carpeta de fuentes
        $fontPath = $this->pdf->getFontPath();

        // Verifica si el archivo de fuente está presente
        $fontFile = $fontPath . '/' . $nombreFuente . '.ttf';

        if (file_exists($fontFile)) {
            // Genera los archivos de fuente
            $fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($fontFile, 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

            // Verifica si el archivo de fuente se generó correctamente
            $fontDefinitionFile = $fontPath . '/' . $fontname . '.php';

            if (file_exists($fontDefinitionFile)) {
                $this->pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 10);
                return true; // Fuente incluida correctamente
            }
        }

        return false; // No se pudo incluir la fuente o generar los archivos de fuente
    }
}

$nombreFuente = 'Graphik-Bold'; // Reemplazar con el nombre de la fuente que desees verificar

// Crear una instancia de la clase TCPDFHandler
$pdf_handler = TCPDFHandler::getInstance();

// Llamada al método de verificación y establecimiento de fuente
if ($pdf_handler->implementFont($nombreFuente)) {
    echo 'La fuente ' . $nombreFuente . ' se ha incluido correctamente en TCPDF.';
} else {
    echo 'No se pudo incluir la fuente ' . $nombreFuente . ' en TCPDF.';
}

// aqui continuas con el codigo tuyo y usando el handler
// $pdf_handler->metodo();
```

***PD:*** Prefiero usar mPDF, en lo personal.